# OS X crops the screenshot when capturing a single, maximised window

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, screenshot

Whenever I make a screen shot of just a single window that is maximised using the shortcut <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, it never accurately captures the full window. Instead, it just saves this:

[image]

What is going on? Why has OS X started doing this? I have been using Snow Leopard for a while, so it is not like that is causing the problems directly. It is also not restricted to Safari. The same thing happens for iTunes, as well as others.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. A window capture adds a shadow border to the image. Perhaps some calculation in the image size has neglected to take into account this border? If you're a registered Apple Developer, you could file a bug report at http://developer.apple.com/bugReporter/

Comment: Thanks, never thought of reporting to to Apple like that! And the window capture does not actually *add* the shadow to the image, it just captures that as well, thanks to window compositing.

Comment: Do other screenshot utilities (Screenshot Plus, for example) have the same symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Apple about this, and they confirmed that it is a bug with Snow Leopard which they are trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens with DVD player, or when your using protected media.  Does this happen if you have the Google Home page in the browser, as the only window (eg no tabs, etc)?

It could be that a plugin that your using is confusing the OS, making it think that there is protected media in the web browser...